# 'Fronting' structure in questions

Tags: grammaticality, questions

From my understanding, in affirmative sentences, the thing we want to mainly talk about can be fronted. as in '*strange people* they are'.

I wonder if such structure is possible with questions. If so, which (kinds) of the following are, either grammatically or idiomatically, acceptable?

1. Good or bad is this plan?
2. Good or bad this plan is?
3. Good or bad do you think this plan is?
4. A good or bad plan this is?
5. A good or bad plan is this?
6. A good or bad plan do you think this is?

Comment: Actually we don't say "Strange people they are." We could say "*What* strange people they are!" But it doesn't work without the *what*. All of your other examples are also incorrect; they're examples of what's sometimes called "Yoda-speak" (after the Star Wars character Yoda, who spoke in this unusual pattern.) I can't think of a way offhand to modify your other examples to make this acceptable; probably because they're questions. You could make a statement like "What a good plan this is!" But in general, just stick with the usual word order.

Comment: _Actually_ actually, plenty of people say things like “strange people, they are” (or even “Strange people, them”). John Lawler calls this “right dislocation” ([#6](http://bit.ly/19Xj3QZ)). It [serves a purpose](http://bit.ly/19Xj3QZ), though [may be particular to BrE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/what-is-this-feature-of-british-english-called).

Comment: Put commas after *bad* in 1-3 and after *plan* in 4-6.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, I would say none of those are acceptable. There are some instances when that *type* of structure is used, but I would not use that in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can often front sentence constituents for emphasis. However, if that results in nonstandard word order, then it can create sentences that sound awkward (or ["Yodaish"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yodaish)). Your original sentence ("strange people they are") would sound awkward in many contexts, and I think that all of your other sentences (numbers 1 through 6) would sound that way in pretty much all contexts. I can't think of any situation in which they would sound natural.

However, we can sometimes front subject complements in questions. Here is one example:

> A bit nervous are we?

If you [search that exact phrase (with quotation marks) in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20bit%20nervous%20are%20we%22), you'll get several results demonstrating that it is quite natural.